# Задержка выполнения php скриптов в bash

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер, bash, cron

Сервер Ubuntu

Есть ряд PHP файлов, которые нужно запустить по очереди, с определенной задержкой.

Можно для каждого настроить время выполнения в cron, но, придется создавать много записей, и при необходимости изменения времени, много править.

Пришла идея по cron'у запускать bash файл, в котором перечислен список php файлов, но не получается выставить интервал запуска. Пытался:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse.php 2>&1
sleep 300
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse2.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

но функцию sleep 300 не понимает, выдает ошибку:

```
sleep: invalid time interval '300\r'
```

Вопрос: как корректно выставить задержку. Либо использовать другие варианты решения задачи, интересно было бы услышать предложения.

**UPD**

Закрыл строки ;

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse.php 2>&1;
sleep 300;
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse2.php >/dev/null 2>&1;
```

кажется, отрабатывает, задержку учитывает.

но в консоли тем не менее выдает ошибки:

```
line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

файл сохранял в notepad++ в формате .bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В линуксе перевод строки это `\n`, а в винде `\r\n`. Вы наверняка писали скрипт под виндой и в файл закрался `\r`. Удалите `\r` и всё заработает (и первый вариант без `;` тоже).

Comment: да, под виндой, но дело в том, что я ни в одном редакторе не вижу этот символ. Как его возможно удалить впринципе?

Comment: @Amsterdam  notepad++ можно установить тип EOL. Вроде `Edit -> EOL Conversion`

Comment: @Amsterdam в консоль ввести команду `sed -i 's/\r//g' /путь к файлу скрипта/имя файла с расширением`